# Regulator to window glass connection on Toyota Yaris

Tags: toyota, power-windows, yaris

Is it possible to to repair or replace the plastic eyelets which connects the regulator the door glass glass?

Comment: Not sure I'm seeing what you are describing. Can you show some pictures of the area you're talking about with a little more detailed description?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy the plastic clips on eBay from around £2($4) the pair. The plastic does not stick well enough, even with super glue. Not really a repairable item.